# Related CLI and GUI applications with same name?

Tags: macos

I'm preparing to release an open source Swift package with two companion MacOS applications: CLI and GUI.  I'm expecting the GUI application to be available via the MacOS App Store.  I'd also like to get the CLI application notarized.

I'd like the naming to be like this for the applications:

```
CLI: applicationname
GUI: ApplicationName.app
```

Is having the same name, other than capitalization and the .app file extension, going to cause trouble with how users access the tools?  Will there be some sort of path resolution conflict given the case-insensitive magic Apple does with the filesystem?

Clarification:

ApplicationName.app has executable ApplicationName inside its package-contents -> Contents -> MacOS directory. But that’s all related to the GUI version. I will also release a separate CLI version, not included in the app bundle, called applicationname.

Comment: Trouble with what? The review process, the installation process, how the user accesses the tool, or something else altogether?

Comment: @nohillside edited question to be more specific. Appreciate if you could reopen.

Comment: Maybe I‘m missing something here but isn‘t this something you can and should test before submitting it to the Store?

Comment: @nohillside Of course I’m testing. But I also seek the experience of the community.  I prefer the same name but once I release changing the CLI name would be...unfortunate.

Comment: you will have two binaries in to different places in the file system. What kind of issues do you worry about here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Nothing of Concern

As long as the application's binary and the command line binary are not stored in the same folder, there are no problems with your naming scheme.

[We ship](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/guide/pmctl) command line tools within the application bundle's `name.app/Contents/Tools/` folder. This has worked well for our customers and is acceptable within Apple's Mac App Store.

### Command line tools and the `PATH`

Your customers, or the installer, may want to place the `applicationname` CLI binary within the [`PATH`](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/bb/cs348/www-S08/unix_path.html), so it can be trivially used from the command line.

By default, the application bundles within the `/Applications` folder are not in the `PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to understand how there could be a conflict in such cases:

- `foo.app` is a directory (usually within `/Applications`) which contains all the files relevant for the application to run (including any resources, translated texts etc)
- `foo` is a binary installed within `foo.app` which can be called from a shell by specificing the path, symlinking it from `/usr/local/bin`, or using any other way available in shells

So this are differently named things of different types, there shouldn’t be a conflict as far as macOS is concerned. We can‘t know what the App Store Review will make of it.

Comment: That’s a helpful observation that ApplicationName.app has executable ApplicationName inside its package-contents -> Contents -> MacOS directory.  But that’s all related to the GUI version. I will also release a separate CLI version, not included in the app bundle, called applicationname.

Comment: @DarrellRoot It doesn't change the answer in case you distribute a separate CLI version (even though I'm not sure this will be possible through the Store). But it might help to add such details to the question itself.

Comment: correct store does not distribute CLI apps because it is an “app” store (this is documented in apples website).  I think notarization of CLI apps is possible.  I’ll try to clarify question.